# Retrieve input from Entry widget stored as an instance variable and use it outside of the class

Tags: python, tkinter

I have difficulties trying to get the input from Entry widget stored as a instance variable, so I can use it as input outside this class:

```
class CreateGUI:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("275x325")
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
        self.checkbutton_var1 = IntVar()
        self.checkbutton_var2 = IntVar()
        self.path = ''
        self.type = []

    def add_labels(self):
        Label(self.master, text="Provide path to file:").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="N")

    def add_entries(self):
        user_input = Entry(self.master)
        user_input.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=60)
        return user_input

    def add_buttons(self, user_input):
        checkbutton1 = Checkbutton(self.master, text="test1", variable=self.checkbutton_var1, onvalue=1,offvalue=0,height=2,width=10)
        checkbutton1.grid(column=1, row=0)
        checkbutton2 = Checkbutton(self.master, text="test2", variable=self.checkbutton_var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0,height=2, width=10)
        checkbutton2.grid(column=1, row=1)
        button = Button(self.master, text="push", bg="pink", bd=100, fg="white",
                    command=lambda: self.retrieve_input(user_input.get(), self.checkbutton_var1.get(), self.checkbutton_var2.get()))
        button.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="NEWS")


    def retrieve_input(self, p, *args):
        self.path = p
        #print(self.path)
        for el in args:
            self.type.append(el)
            #print(self.type)

def main():
    tk = Tk()
    app = CreateGUI(tk)
    app.add_labels()
    user_input = app.add_entries()
    app.add_buttons(user_input)
    print(app.type)
    print(app.path)
    tk.mainloop()
```

When I start the program, write the input and press the button, it does not print anything. There are empty brackets printed the moment the program is initiated. The prints inside the `retrieve_input` are printing exactly what I need, but I need this inputs outside of the class, because they will be an input to another class.

I tried everything related to this problem, but it is not working and I would really appriciate any kind of help. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Because it is printed as soon as the entry is created, before the use even has a change to input

Comment: @Sujay Ok I see, but how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the input for the Entry widget right before anyone can have a chance to type in it. As a result, `user_input.get()` will return an empty string. One thing  you can do is make some sort of trigger for calling `add_buttons()` that the user activates when they are done filling out `user_input`. Further tweaking after that should make it work.

Please tell me if you have any more trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I think this might work, it is not ideal, but I can't think of other solution.